# AutoMapper: read Mapper Configuration at runtime?

Tags: excel, automapper, datareader

Please forgive me if I get any of the AutoMapper lingo incorrect, I'm new to the library.

## My Code

I've created this `Map` for the purpose of mapping from an `IDataReader` to a `PersonDto`. The code works great, I'm able generate `PersonDto` objects from the `IDataReader`. No problems there.

```
var map = CreateMap<IDataReader, PersonDto>()
    .ForMember(o => o.FirstName, opt => opt.MapFrom(row => row["First Name"]))
    .ForMember(o => o.LastName, opt => opt.MapFrom(row => row["Last Name"]))
    .ForMember(o => o.Birthday, opt => opt.MapFrom(row => row["Date of Birth"]))
```

## My Question

I'm looking for some way to take `map` as defined above, and get back the strings `{“First Name”, “Last Name”, “Date of Birth”}`.

## Why I Want To Do This (what is my goal)

*This section is just-in-case anyone is scratching their heads as to why I would want to do the above. As I mentioned, I’m new to the library, so I don’t know if what I’m asking for is counter Automapper’s intended use.*

I’m using the [ExcelDataReader](https://github.com/ExcelDataReader/ExcelDataReader) library to read data from an Excel spreadsheet. The xlsx comes from a 3rd party vendor, and every few months they change the layout of the xlsx (reorder/rename headers). They do not offer a web API or other way to get the data.

What's more, the location of the header row is unpredictable. The vendor inserts charts above the data on the same worksheet. To solve that problem, I wrote a function that given the header names, will return the index of the header row:

```
   string headerNames[] = {“First Name”, “Last Name” ...}
   int headerIndex = findHeaderRow(dataReader, headerNames)
```

I want to be able to obtain the header names from the AutoMapper configuration so that I can feed them directly into `findHeaderRow`, without having to explicitly define the string array.

I could create my map like this, but it smells fragile to me.

```
var map = CreateMap<IDataReader, PersonDto>()
    .ForMember(o => o.FirstName, opt => opt.MapFrom(row => row[headerNames[0]]))
    .ForMember(o => o.LastName, opt => opt.MapFrom(row => row[headerNames[1]]))
```

### Conclusion

Ultimately, what I want is for this Excel import code to be simple to update when these inevitable layout changes occur. I want the header names to be defined in just one place, and the best place that I see is in the AutoMapper configuration.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with. It works, I just don't know how robust it is, or if there is a better way to do this.

```
public static string[] GetSourceColumnNames<TSource, TDestination>(MapperConfiguration config) {

    var maps = config.ResolveTypeMap(typeof(TSource), typeof(TDestination)).GetPropertyMaps();

    string[] columnNames = new string[maps.Length];

    for (int i = 0; i < maps.Length; i++)
    {
        var body = maps[i].CustomExpression.Body;

        if (body is IArgumentProvider)
        {
            var provider = (IArgumentProvider)body;
            if (provider.ArgumentCount > 0)
            {
                columnNames[i] = provider.GetArgument(0).ToString().Trim('"');
            }
        }
    }       
    return columnNames;
}
```

Comment: I think you should take those strings from the data reader, not from AM.

Comment: The strings are not defined in the `DataReader`. The column names inside the Excel file can change at any time.

Comment: I don't know about that, but surely what you have now is...not good :)

Comment: It's over engineered. It takes a simple problem and solves it in an convoluted way. While I can see your point, the end result... I'm not really willing to research this, but even having named constants for the column names or indices seems better.

Comment: You're probably right about over engineering. I'm doing too much work to avoid named constants / double-mapping. Back to the drawing board.